# Magento remove reindex bar in admin

Tags: magento, reindex

I have an API script that updates the prices in Magento and does a reindex. This occurs every minute. So when this happens you can see the "One or more of the Indexes are not up to date" in the backend.

Is there a way that I can easily remove this bar from the backend?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do that via CSS, but I honestly have to question the motivation of updating prices once per minute.  That is going to be incredibly costly in terms of bandwidth and CPU time, unless you have like 5 products.

Comment: Definitely - there's a reason it's a generated index in the first place instead of running all of that on the fly. I'd be careful with this.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the feedback. In this case it's about 48 products that actually change every minute. (not the products, but the prices)
You suggest another method? Can I do it any diffrent?

Comment: If you honestly need the products to change every min then you don't have a whole lot of options here.  1: if only a couple of the products actually change every min, then a couple more later etc.  I would suggest directly manipulating the index tables. 2: if every product changes every min, you may need to find a way to avoid using the index, or just bite the performance bullet and reindex every time.